# Find and replace lines in text file with output from another file

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, grep, bioinformatics

I have two files A and B.

```
File A
>Node1                  
...
>Node2
...

File B
>gb|KY551314.1| Influenza A virus (A/mallard/Idaho/AH0011522/2015(H7N7)) segment 
2 polymerase PB1 (PB1) and PB1-F2 protein (PB1-F2) genes, 
complete cds
Length=2316

>gb|KY561069.1| Influenza A virus (A/American green-winged teal/Missouri/15OS6591/2015(H11N9)) 
segment 1 polymerase PB2 (PB2) gene, complete 
cds
Length=2341
```

How can I replace each NodeX line of File A with the subsequent entries in File B? The result would look like the following:

```
File A
>gb|KY551314.1| Influenza A virus (A/mallard/Idaho/AH0011522/2015(H7N7)) segment 2 polymerase PB1 (PB1) and PB1-F2 protein (PB1-F2) genes, complete ads Length=2316
...

>gb|KY561069.1| Influenza A virus (A/American green-winged teal/Missouri/15OS6591/2015(H11N9)) segment 1 polymerase PB2 (PB2) gene, complete ads Length=2341
...
```

Comment: How are they to be matched up? Just sequentially?

Comment: Yes, sequentially.

Comment: unclear, `FileA` should be just replaced with `FileB` contents as is?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest See edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it with `awk`:

```
awk 'NR==FNR && /^>Node/ {
    $0 = ""
    for(i=0; i<=4; i++) {
        getline s <ARGV[2]
        $0 = $0 s
    }
}
NR==FNR' FileA FileB
```

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -lMautodie -pe 'BEGIN{ open FILE_B, "<", pop; }
   s/^>Node.*// && do{for my $k (0..3) { s/$/<FILE_B> =~ s|\n| |r/e }}
' FileA FileB
```

---

#### Explanation

- Perl options: `-l` => `IFS=OFS=\n`, `-p` => implicit file read in loop + autoprint records.
- `autodie` pragma included to bailout on errors.
- open the FileB
- for line matching >Node in the beginning of FileA, we read FileB 4 times and removes newlines.